# Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows

Tags: bash, command-history

I consistently have more than one terminal open. Anywhere from two to ten, doing various bits and bobs. Now let's say I restart and open up another set of terminals. Some remember certain things, some forget.

I want a history that:

- Remembers everything from every terminal
- Is instantly accessible from every terminal (eg if I `ls` in one, switch to another already-running terminal and then press up, `ls` shows up)
- Doesn't forget command if there are spaces at the front of the command.

Anything I can do to make bash work more like that?

Comment: I know zsh handles the first point fine, but I've never seen anything handle the second point. What do you mean by the last one? I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: I can see the advantage of that, but personally i would HATE that in my shell. I usually keep 3 or 4 tabs open in my terminal for very specific uses: one for running 'make', one with vi, one to run stuff, etc. So when I compile, I go to tab 1, hit up and 'make' comes up, and so on. This is extremely productive to me. So if suddenly I go to my 'make' tab and hit up and some random grep command shows up, I'd get really pissed off! Just a personal note though

Comment: @axel_c that's true enough. I can't think of an intelligent way to do it where existing terminals only see their own history but new ones see a chronologically accurate list of commands.

Comment: @durin42 actually... zsh handles the second point to if you set up the history stuff right.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103944/real-time-history-export-amongst-bash-terminal-windows

Comment: @Oli wrote, "I can't think of an intelligent way to do it where existing terminals only see their own history but new ones see a chronologically accurate list of commands." How about (untried): `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`. Existing shells will add each command to the history file for new shells to see, but only show their own histories.

Comment: Do you want the history all stored separately or all merged into a single history file?

Comment: @kbyrd: in one file. Q edited with that info.

Comment: @Axel_c: If we could tweak it per terminal, then we have the best of the both worlds.

Comment: Short answer is: it's not intended by bash developers. Solutions based on flushing then re-reading the history probably do work, but beware of [Shlemiel The Painter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ShlemielThePainter). In plain words: amount of processing work between each command is proportional to history size.

Comment: A note on the solutions generally: I have implemented something like the solutions in the answers below on my machine. I have had an occasional problem with race conditions. I have tried overcoming this using a mutex-like `flock`. Unfortunately even that is not quite 'atomic'; often the mutex fails gracefully (as intended; most often when the system re-opens terminals following a power-up); but (very rarely) it also fails gracelessly, and results in an empty (shared) history file. (So, I periodically make a copy and a backup. I should try debugging further…)

Comment: @axel_c I have posted a separate question about sharing history without mixing commands from different sessions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421868/share-shell-history-across-sessions-without-interleaving-it

Comment: @axel_c I come up with a solution that doesn't mix history from individual sessions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430128/32950

Comment: Probably this is the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18443/129967) with detailed explanation

Comment: @EugenKonkov In fact, if one does not care about duplicate entries, [fstang's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309087/154671) down below appears better.

Comment: Also consider this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834786/command-history-and-use-of-multiple-terminals

Answer (score 464, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
# Avoid duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Comment: The problem with this PROMPT_COMMAND solution is that the numbers for each history item changes after each command :(. For example if you type history and 1) ls 2) rm, then you do !1 to repeat 1, the history number might change and might run the rm command...

Comment: When I do this, other already-open terminals don't have the last entered command when I press 'Up' until after I issue a command in _that_ terminal - is this expected? If so, is there a way to truly modify other terminals' history instantly?

Comment: @Suan, this seems right to me based on the commands.  I found that we can issue a null command (just press enter key) to get the history to update.

Comment: Could I put this setting globally in global bashrc so that it overrides settings for all users ?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to set ignoredups, if you already do erasedups?

Comment: Actually *`history -a` (...) does not trigger erasing duplicates* according to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18443/5355) answer to the question [Bash history: “ignoredups” and “erasedups” setting conflict with common history across sessions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18212/5355). This answer also gives the sequence of `history -<option>` commands that works with `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups` setting.

Comment: There is no reason to `export` the `HISTCONTROL` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` variables: you are defining them in `.bashrc` so they will be defined in every shell (even in non-interactive ones, which is also wasteful).

Comment: I am trying to adopt this trick on Mac OS. It works great on a regular bash session where `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is set to `update_terminal_cwd`, a function set in line 9 of `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` (found via a trick learned [here](http://superuser.com/questions/144772/finding-the-definition-of-a-bash-function)). But inside a *screen* session, `$PROMPT_COMMAND` becomes an empty string, which means `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` is probably not executed anymore. Do you know why? I tested that such problem doesn't happen on CentOS 6.7, where $PROMPT_COMMAND was set very differently.

Comment: @ChrisKimpton history numbers dont change when added to history file a line witch you read with history command. It reads as it is already in history file. Executing !1 will be from that file executed. Added are only to number 3 n 4 n 5 etc not overwriting. Executing command is adding a line after all previious at end and not changing some previous.

Comment: I recommend renaming HISTFILE as well - otherwise a single terminal can overwrite your entire history if run even once (as happened to me a few times before I changed HISTFILE).

Comment: It looks like the `PROMPT_COMMAND` in this answer breaks the `ignoredups:erasedups`, which intends to remove already existing duplicate entries. If you repeatedly alternate between two commands, and then look at the last several lines in the history, we can see that there are duplicates.

Comment: @DeanM Incorrect solution: a shell script launched from a terminal has access to the terminal but is still non interactive (see the INVOCATION section of the bash manual).

Comment: @dolmen  In order to avoid the definitions in non-interactive shells, add this: `if [ -z "${PS1}" ]; then return; fi`.

Comment: Related to @dolmen's comment: [using export in .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107851/154671)

Comment: Is the third `$` in the variable expansion a typo?

Comment: Why is the history -c command needed? I anyone has a clue, please provide some details.

Comment: Consider this fantastic guide (search for "shopt"): https://catonmat.net/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history

Comment: @dolmen @DeanM `.bashrc` runs only for interactive shells. Neither `bash -c '...'`, nor `bash script.sh`, nor `./script.sh` will execute the rc file. To confirm this yourself, add `echo bashrc` into your rc file or use `strace --trace=file` if you are paranoid.

Comment: @ChrisKimpton I use `!?` or ctrl-r more often anyways, so that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 301):

So, this is all my history-related `.bashrc` thing:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it

# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Tested with bash 3.2.17 on Mac OS X 10.5, bash 4.1.7 on 10.6.

Comment: The PS1 trick didn't work on AIX either, but this did! +1

Comment: Hmm.. This kills the ability to use $ !34, as the command numbers change every prompt.  Is there a workaround @Davide @Schof @kch?

Comment: Not really a workaround, but I certainly feel less the need to use history replacements by using the arrow keys for history search. That is, it search lines in history starting with whatever you typed so far. In `.inputrc`:


    "\e[B": history-search-forward
    "\e[A": history-search-backward

Comment: @Charles Merriam see lesmana's answer. I now updated mine with the relevant bit.

Comment: Use this to get infinite history:  [bash eternal history](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/543).  HOWEVER, this is complimentary to the code above, since it won't be reloaded automatically.

Comment: FYI None of the solutions mentioned here can solve the following problem. I have two shell windows A and B. In shell window A, I run `sleep 9999`, and (without waiting for the sleep to finish) in shell window B, I want to be able to see `sleep 9999` in the bash history.

Comment: @pts: Try `trap 'history -a; history -c; history -r;' DEBUG` instead of `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: @Xiong Chiamiov: how exactly should the resulting line be then? I cannot get this working

Comment: @XiongChiamiov, yes I'd like to see that as well.

Comment: @pts I too was aiming for live behavior, but then I realized it is more convenient to have terminal specific histories which make working on different things in different terminals easier. I found this to be very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338285/#answer-7449399 Based on that, I made myself an alias called `href` that refreshes the history of my current terminal instantly and cleans up the history file in the process. Whenever I open a new terminal, that cleanup/sync is executed in my bashrc file so the new terminal has the latest history. I'm using that along with `history -a`

Comment: Another problem with PROMPT_COMMAND is if the long-running process (e.g. `sleep 999`) and the shell are both killed (because e.g. the terminal window is closed), then the command won't ever be saved to any history file. (The script I wrote solves this.)

Comment: Another problem with calling `history -r` at each prompt is that it's too slow (more than 0.2 sec) as soon as there are tens of thousands of entries. (The script I wrote solves this.)

Comment: Another problem with simplistic approaches like `history -a; history -c; history -r` is that commands are not merged in execution order, i.e. they don't guarantee pressing the *Up* key repeatedly would show commands in (reverse) order they were executed. (The script I wrote solves this by prepending the timestamp to each command.)

Comment: Could I put this setting globally in global bashrc so that it overrides settings for all users ?

Comment: @trusktr can you share your code for href?

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: There is no reason to `export` the variables: you are defining them in `.bashrc` so they will be defined in every shell (even in non-interactive ones, which is also wasteful)

Comment: This solution is much faster than Pablo R.'s popular answer. The prompt does not pause. I think my hist size was too big for this to work efficiently.

Comment: I recommend renaming HISTFILE as well - otherwise a single terminal can overwrite your entire history if run even once (as happened to me a few times before I changed HISTFILE).

Comment: @dolmen Actually, there is also a strong reason to not do `export PROMPT_COMMAND`, as doing so will result in stale "Window Title" when inside a screen session.

Comment: This puts each line of multi-line commands as separate commands in the history file. Viz., `cmdhist` works (multi-line commands converted to single-line ones separated with `;`), but `lithist` (which uses `\n` instead) results in splitting multi-line commands into different commands/lines/entries in the history.

Answer (score 138):

Here is my attempt at Bash session history sharing. This will enable history sharing between bash sessions in a way that the history counter does not get mixed up and history expansion like `!number` will work (with some constraints).

Using Bash version 4.1.5 under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

```
HISTSIZE=9000
HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoredups

_bash_history_sync() {
    builtin history -a         #1
    HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE     #2
    builtin history -c         #3
    builtin history -r         #4
}

history() {                  #5
    _bash_history_sync
    builtin history "$@"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_bash_history_sync
```

### Explanation:

1. Append the just entered line to the `$HISTFILE` (default is `.bash_history`). This will cause `$HISTFILE` to grow by one line.
2. Setting the special variable `$HISTFILESIZE` to some value will cause Bash to truncate `$HISTFILE` to be no longer than `$HISTFILESIZE` lines by removing the oldest entries.
3. Clear the history of the running session. This will reduce the history counter by the amount of `$HISTSIZE`.
4. Read the contents of `$HISTFILE` and insert them in to the current running session history. this will raise the history counter by the amount of lines in `$HISTFILE`. Note that the line count of `$HISTFILE` is not necessarily `$HISTFILESIZE`.
5. The `history()` function overrides the builtin history to make sure that the history is synchronised before it is displayed. This is necessary for the history expansion by number (more about this later).

### More explanation:

- Step 1 ensures that the command from the current running session gets written to the global history file.
- Step 4 ensures that the commands from the other sessions gets read in to the current session history.
- Because step 4 will raise the history counter, we need to reduce the counter in some way. This is done in step 3.
- In step 3 the history counter is reduced by `$HISTSIZE`. In step 4 the history counter is raised by the number of lines in `$HISTFILE`. In step 2 we make sure that the line count of `$HISTFILE` is exactly `$HISTSIZE` (this means that `$HISTFILESIZE` must be the same as `$HISTSIZE`).

### About the constraints of the history expansion:

When using history expansion by number, you should **always** look up the number **immediately** before using it. That means no bash prompt display between looking up the number and using it. That usually means no enter and no ctrl+c.

Generally, once you have more than one Bash session, there is no guarantee whatsoever that a history expansion by number will retain its value between two Bash prompt displays. Because when `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed the history from all other Bash sessions are integrated in the history of the current session. If any other bash session has a new command then the history numbers of the current session will be different.

I find this constraint reasonable. I have to look the number up every time anyway because I can't remember arbitrary history numbers.

Usually I use the history expansion by number like this

```
$ history | grep something #note number
$ !number
```

I recommend using the following Bash options.

```
## reedit a history substitution line if it failed
shopt -s histreedit
## edit a recalled history line before executing
shopt -s histverify
```

### Strange bugs:

Running the history command piped to anything will result that command to be listed in the history twice. For example:

```
$ history | head
$ history | tail
$ history | grep foo
$ history | true
$ history | false
```

All will be listed in the history twice. I have no idea why.

### Ideas for improvements:

- Modify the function `_bash_history_sync()` so it does not execute every time. For example it should not execute after a `CTRL+C` on the prompt. I often use `CTRL+C` to discard a long command line when I decide that I do not want to execute that line. Sometimes I have to use `CTRL+C` to stop a Bash completion script.
- Commands from the current session should always be the most recent in the history of the current session. This will also have the side effect that a given history number keeps its value for history entries from this session.

Comment: Why not "history -n" (reload lines not already loaded) instead of "history -c; history -r" ?

Comment: @Graham: I did not want to use `history -n` because it messes up the history counter. Also, I found `history -n` to be too unreliable.

Comment: One disadvantage: Commands with multi-line strings are normally still preserved in the current session. With this trick, they are split into individual lines instantly. Using -n for -c -r does not help, neither does cmdhist or lithist. I don't think there is a workaround at this point.

Comment: After trying this for a bit, I've actually found that running only `history -a`, without `-c` and `-r`, is better usability-wise (though it's not what the question asked). It means commands you run are available instantly in new shells even before exiting the current shell, but not in concurrently running shells. This way Arrow-Up still always selects the last-run commands *of the current session*, which I find much less confusing.

Comment: outstandingly good answer, this works reliably unlike the more common "history -a; history -n"

Comment: for some working bash code that includes this and other features, see https://github.com/RichVel/nicer-bash-prompt

Comment: Do you know of any way to share history between my user and root? I don't have any security concerns and it would be a time saver for me.

Comment: @BrianGordon - there's no secure way to do this really, but you could try pointing HISTFILE to ~youruser/.bashhistory_shared, for both youruser and root.  You might as well share the .bashrc as well, which can be done by doing a simple '. ~youruser/.bashrc' in root's .bashrc.

Comment: This solution causes running a standard `history -c` to not work.

Comment: @JoLiss: agree with `Arrow-Up` *not* turning up random commands from other sessions in the current one, but I do want `Ctrl+r` to search among all commands. Any way to [do both](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684889/search-through-bash-history-shared-by-multiple-terminal-windows-but-keep-sessio)?

Answer (score 57):

I'm not aware of any way using `bash`. But it's one of the most popular features of [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/).
Personally I prefer `zsh` over `bash` so I recommend trying it.

Here's the part of my `.zshrc` that deals with history:

```
SAVEHIST=10000 # Number of entries
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh/history # File
setopt APPEND_HISTORY # Don't erase history
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY # Add additional data to history like timestamp
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY # Add immediately
setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS # Don't show duplicates in search
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE # Don't preserve spaces. You may want to turn it off
setopt NO_HIST_BEEP # Don't beep
setopt SHARE_HISTORY # Share history between session/terminals
```

Comment: JFTR [_names are case insensitive and underscores are ignored_](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions).

Comment: ``setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY`` is enough

Answer (score 19):

To do this, you'll need to add two lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;history -c;history -r;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

From `man bash`:

> If the histappend shell option is enabled (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below), the lines are appended to the history file, otherwise the history file is over-written.

Answer (score 13):

You can edit your BASH prompt to run the "history -a" and "history -r" that Muerr suggested:

```
savePS1=$PS1
```

(in case you mess something up, which is almost guaranteed)

```
PS1=$savePS1`history -a;history -r`
```

(note that these are back-ticks; they'll run history -a and history -r on every prompt. Since they don't output any text, your prompt will be unchanged.

Once you've got your PS1 variable set up the way you want, set it permanently it in your ~/.bashrc file.

If you want to go back to your original prompt while testing, do:

```
PS1=$savePS1
```

I've done basic testing on this to ensure that it sort of works, but can't speak to any side-effects from running `history -a;history -r` on every prompt.

Comment: kch's solution works better than mine does. I'm now using his solution in my .bashrc.

Comment: Gotta say, I like this one. As little script to toggle on/off seems right.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an alternative that I use.  It's cumbersome but it addresses the issue that @axel_c mentioned where sometimes you may want to have a separate history instance in each terminal (one for make, one for monitoring, one for vim, etc).

I keep a separate appended history file that I constantly update.  I have the following mapped to a hotkey:

```
history | grep -v history >> ~/master_history.txt
```

This appends all history from the current terminal to a file called master_history.txt in your home dir.

I also have a separate hotkey to search through the master history file:

```
cat /home/toby/master_history.txt | grep -i
```

I use cat | grep because it leaves the cursor at the end to enter my regex.  A less ugly way to do this would be to add a couple of scripts to your path to accomplish these tasks, but hotkeys work for my purposes.  I also periodically will pull history down from other hosts I've worked on and append that history to my master_history.txt file.

It's always nice to be able to quickly search and find that tricky regex you used or that weird perl one-liner you came up with 7 months ago.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `history -a` to append the current session's history to the histfile, then use `history -r` on the other terminals to read the histfile.

Answer (score 11):

If you need a bash or zsh history synchronizing solution which also solves the problem below, then see it at http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-automatically-synchronize-shell.html

The problem is the following: I have two shell windows A and B. In shell window A, I run `sleep 9999`, and (without waiting for the sleep to finish) in shell window B, I want to be able to see `sleep 9999` in the bash history.

The reason why most other solutions here won't solve this problem is that they are writing their history changes to the the history file using `PROMPT_COMMAND` or `PS1`, both of which are executing too late, only after the `sleep 9999` command has finished.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I got a few questions though.

1. Can I use the original .bash_history file, I do not want another bash history file existed in my $HOME
2. May be you should consider set a github repo for this.

Comment: It seems the debug hook is conflicted with bashdb, the follow output every time I start a bash session.

```
bash debugger, bashdb, release 4.2-0.8

Copyright 2002, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 Rocky Bernstein
This is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.

** Internal debug error _Dbg_is_file(): file argument null
bash: _Dbg_filenames[$fullname]: bad array subscript
```

Comment: @Techlive Zheng: 1. The original .bash_history is deliberately not supported, because .merged_bash_history uses a different file format, so in case .merged_bash_history fails to load properly, bash won't accidentally clobber the accumulated history. Robustness by design, will be kept as is. 2. A github repo is a good idea in general, but I don't have time to maintain that for this project, so I'm not doing it. -- Yes, it conflicts with bashdb, and there is no easy solution (they use the same hooks). I'm not planning to work on a fix, but I'm accepting patches.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have come up with a much simple and better sulotion.

Comment: @TechliveZheng: Would you share your simple and better solution with us, so we all can learn from it? (If so, please add an answer to the question.)

Comment: @psts, It turns out that it is not your script incompatible with bashdb. When `shopt -s extdebug` is set or `bash --debugger` is invoked in an interactive mode, the bashdb always complaines about the 'null filename' issue. It seems `shopt -s extdebug` and `bash --debugger` are not supposed to be run in interacive mode. Unfortunately, they don't handle this situation well.

Answer (score 11):

Right, So finally this annoyed me to find a decent solution:

```
# Write history after each command
_bash_history_append() {
    builtin history -a
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="_bash_history_append; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

What this does is sort of amalgamation of what was said in this thread, except that I don't understand why would you reload the global history after every command. I very rarely care about what happens in other terminals, but I always run series of commands, say in one terminal:

```
make
ls -lh target/*.foo
scp target/artifact.foo vm:~/
```

(Simplified example)

And in another:

```
pv ~/test.data | nc vm:5000 >> output
less output
mv output output.backup1
```

No way I'd want the command to be shared

Comment: The reason you'd reload the history after every command is that it's the behaviour required by the question (and so this doesn't actually answer the question as posed).

Comment: @MichaelHomer Fair point. Feel free to downvote so the answer stays at the bottom, however, I would chalk this up to the OP not realising how bad the requested behaviour would be, and the fact that this is very googlable question.

Comment: Op here, yeah, that's a fair compromise. My main complaint is that I was losing history. This should stop that, even if it doesn't mean instant updates across simultaneous sessions.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my enhancement to @lesmana's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48116/45761). The main difference is that concurrent windows don't share history. This means you can keep working in your windows, without having context from other windows getting loaded into your current windows.

If you explicitly type 'history', OR if you open a new window then you get the history from all previous windows.

Also, I use [this strategy](https://debian-administration.org/article/543/Bash_eternal_history) to archive every command ever typed on my machine.

```
# Consistent and forever bash history
HISTSIZE=100000
HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoredups

_bash_history_sync() {
  builtin history -a         #1
  HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE     #2
}

_bash_history_sync_and_reload() {
  builtin history -a         #1
  HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE     #2
  builtin history -c         #3
  builtin history -r         #4
}

history() {                  #5
  _bash_history_sync_and_reload
  builtin history "$@"
}

export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S   "
PROMPT_COMMAND='history 1 >> ${HOME}/.bash_eternal_history'
PROMPT_COMMAND=_bash_history_sync;$PROMPT_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 8):

I chose to put history in a file-per-tty, as multiple people can be working on the same server - separating each session's commands makes it easier to audit.

```
# Convert /dev/nnn/X or /dev/nnnX to "nnnX"
HISTSUFFIX=`tty | sed 's/\///g;s/^dev//g'`
# History file is now .bash_history_pts0
HISTFILE=".bash_history_$HISTSUFFIX"
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace
shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=5000
```

History now looks like:

```
user@host:~# test 123
user@host:~# test 5451
user@host:~# history
1  15-08-11 10:09:58 test 123
2  15-08-11 10:10:00 test 5451
3  15-08-11 10:10:02 history
```

With the files looking like:

```
user@host:~# ls -la .bash*
-rw------- 1 root root  4275 Aug 11 09:42 .bash_history_pts0
-rw------- 1 root root    75 Aug 11 09:49 .bash_history_pts1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3120 Aug 11 10:09 .bashrc
```

Answer (score 7):

I can offer a fix for that last one: make sure the env variable HISTCONTROL does not specify "ignorespace" (or "ignoreboth").

But I feel your pain with multiple concurrent sessions. It simply isn't handled well in bash.

Answer (score 7):

Here I will point out one problem with

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

and

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;history -a; history -n"
```

If you run source ~/.bashrc, the $PROMPT_COMMAND will be like

```
"history -a; history -c; history -r history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

and

```
"history -a; history -n history -a; history -n"
```

This repetition occurs each time you run 'source ~/.bashrc'. You can check PROMPT_COMMAND after each time you run 'source ~/.bashrc' by running 'echo $PROMPT_COMMAND'.

You could see some commands are apparently broken: "history -n history -a". But the good news is that it still works, because other parts still form a valid command sequence (Just involving some extra cost due to executing some commands repetitively. And not so clean.)

Personally I use the following simple version:

```bsh
shopt -s histappend
_bash_history_append() {
    builtin history -a
    builtin history -c
    builtin history -r
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="_bash_history_append;${PROMPT_COMMAND#"_bash_history_append;"}
```

which has most of the functionalities while no such issue as mentioned above.

It is good to prepend `_bash_history_append` to default `PROMPT_COMMAND`, because in default
we can have something like `__vte_prompt_command`, which will keep current directory when opening
new tabs in gnome-terminal etc.

So we remove prefix `_bash_history_append` from `PROMPT_COMMAND` and so there are no repetitions.

Another point to make is: **there is really nothing magic**.
PROMPT_COMMAND is just a plain bash environment variable. The commands in it get executed before you get bash prompt (the $ sign). For example, your PROMPT_COMMAND is "echo 123", and you run "ls" in your terminal. The effect is like running "ls; echo 123".

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo 123"
```

output (Just like running 'PROMPT_COMMAND="echo 123"; $PROMPT_COMMAND'):

```
123
```

Run the following:

```
$ echo 3
```

output:

```
3
123
```

"history -a" is used to write the history commands in memory to ~/.bash_history

"history -c" is used to clear the history commands in memory

"history -r" is used to read history commands from ~/.bash_history to memory

See history command explanation here: http://ss64.com/bash/history.html

PS: As other users have pointed out, **export** is unnecessary. See: [Using export in .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/using-export-in-bashrc)

Comment: I needed to change it your solution, because new gnom-terminal tabs didn't keep current directory. First I looked what is originally with `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`. Then my code is: `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;history -c;history -r;__vte_prompt_command"`

Answer (score 4):

I have written a script for setting a history file per session or task its based off the following.

```
        # write existing history to the old file
        history -a

        # set new historyfile
        export HISTFILE="$1"
        export HISET=$1

        # touch the new file to make sure it exists
        touch $HISTFILE
        # load new history file
        history -r $HISTFILE
```

It doesn't necessary save every history command but it saves the ones that i care about and its easier to retrieve them then going through every command. My version also lists all history files and provides the ability to search through them all.

Full source: https://github.com/simotek/scripts-config/blob/master/hiset.sh

Answer (score 3):

This works for ZSH

```
##############################################################################
# History Configuration for ZSH
##############################################################################
HISTSIZE=10000               #How many lines of history to keep in memory
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history     #Where to save history to disk
SAVEHIST=10000               #Number of history entries to save to disk
#HISTDUP=erase               #Erase duplicates in the history file
setopt    appendhistory     #Append history to the history file (no overwriting)
setopt    sharehistory      #Share history across terminals
setopt    incappendhistory  #Immediately append to the history file, not just when a term is killed
```

Comment: unfortunately the question is strictly for bash :-)

Comment: its the first result on google when i search for zsh as well...Thought it might help

Comment: You should ask a new question, ~"Preserve zsh history in multiple terminal windows", assuming one doesn't already exist. It's perfectly okay —even encouraged— to answer your own question if it's a good question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that *doesn't* mix up histories from individual sessions!

Basically one has to store history of each session separately and recreate it on every prompt. Yes, it uses more resources, but it's not as slow as it may sound - delay starts to be noticeable only if you have more than 100000 history entries.

Here's the core logic:

```
# on every prompt, save new history to dedicated file and recreate full history
# by reading all files, always keeping history from current session on top.
update_history () {
  history -a ${HISTFILE}.$$
  history -c
  history -r
  for f in `ls ${HISTFILE}.[0-9]* | grep -v "${HISTFILE}.$$\$"`; do
    history -r $f
  done
  history -r "${HISTFILE}.$$"
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='update_history'

# merge session history into main history file on bash exit
merge_session_history () {
  cat ${HISTFILE}.$$ >> $HISTFILE
  rm ${HISTFILE}.$$
}
trap merge_session_history EXIT
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jan-warchol/89f5a748f7e8a2c9e91c9bc1b358d3ec) for a full solution, including some safeguards and performance optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to start a sqlite db, for me I'm just tired of having to recreate long commands. This is just an outline but I think it could easily be made to meet your exact ask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# drop in bashrc
# bash history in sqlite, i hate losing commands
# run bh to see recent history
#
function create_db() (
    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db  ";" || return

    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db "CREATE TABLE commands( \
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
        last_used INTEGER, \
        command TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );" 2>/dev/null || true

    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_command ON commands(command);" 2>/dev/null || true
    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_last_used ON commands(last_used);" 2>/dev/null || true
)

function update_history() {
    LAST=`builtin history 1|awk -F' ' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ",$i}'`
    DATE=$(date +%s)
    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db "UPDATE commands SET last_used='$DATE' WHERE command='$LAST';"
    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO commands (last_used, command) VALUES ('$DATE', '$LAST' );"
}

function bh(){
    sqlite3 ~/.bash_db "SELECT * FROM commands ORDER BY last_used DESC LIMIT 50;"
}

create_db
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_history; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Just a warning there are a number of issues with this, I will eventually update it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply keep individual history files for each tab by using the tty ID? I don't speak bash, but with tcsh you can do this:

```
set histfile=~/.history_`tty|sed "s#^.*/##"`
```

This approach should also work in bash, probably just by:

```
export HISTFILE=~/.history_`tty|sed "s#^.*/##"`
```

As HISTFILE is evaluated at the start of each session, it will also automatically restore the associated history file on initialization.

Add to this the other features using PROMPT_COMMAND etc.

Answer (score 2):

I long wanted this, especially the ability to retrieve a command by where it was run to re-execute in a new project (or find a directory by a command). So I put [this tool](https://github.com/gawells/ariadne) together, which combines previous solutions for storing a global CLI history with an interactive grepping tool called percol (mapped to C^R). It's still slick on the first machine I started using it, now with a >2 year old CLI history.

It doesn't mess with the local CLI history as far as arrow keys are concerned, but lets you access the global history quite easily (which you can also map to something other than C^R)

Comment: this is for zsh?

Comment: yes, I made it for zsh initially. Got it working for bash and fish too though. Let me know if it works or not. I haven't changed it in a while and I'm not sure how clear I've been in my install instructions

Answer (score 2):

Because I prefer infinite history which saved in custom file. I create this configuration based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533853/4632019:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "

export HISTFILE=~/.bash_myhistory
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 2):

While I like being able to share history between terminals, especially new terminals.  I would not want to share each and every command as it happens, as one window is often doing a specific task, separate form other windows.  I would have them merge on shell exit, or when I request.

For a long time I looked for a way to merge bash history (with timestamps), and nothing seemed acceptable to me...

Finally I just 'bit the bullet' and DIY'ed a script to merge, the on-disk ".bash_history" with the in-memory shell 'history'. Preserving timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Now when I source this (you could make it a alias or a function as you like), I use the alias 'hc'.  My current shell session is merged between disk and memory, so history is updated from other previous merges, WHEN I WANT (or on logout from that shell via ".bash_logout").

Optionally you can remove unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's. Adjust to suit!

This is the result... https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to the question, or it is. It depends on how you look at it. Apparently, `bash` doesn't support this out of the box. And it's not like for no reason, if you think about it. To implement this it [has to](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter) write to the history file (while keeping it unduplicated) before executing every command, and read every time it needs history. Do you think a file would still suffice? Well, you might use locks, but considering that some indexing would be in order, it must be easier to just make use of some sort of database. And to top it all, do you really want all shells to have common history? Do you not use Up to reexecute command from the current shell? Do you not use `sudo !!`?

So what I suggest is KISS (be practical):

```
shopt -s histappend
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
```

When you want to execute a command in another shell, do `history -a`, then in another shell `history -n`, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet from my .bashrc and short explanations wherever needed:

```
# The following line ensures that history logs screen commands as well
shopt -s histappend

# This line makes the history file to be rewritten and reread at each bash prompt
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;history -a; history -n"
# Have lots of history
HISTSIZE=100000         # remember the last 100000 commands
HISTFILESIZE=100000     # start truncating commands after 100000 lines
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth  # ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and     ignoredups
```

The HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE are personal preferences and you can change them as per your tastes.