# How to get a persistent "history"-file even after a non-clean shutdown?

Tags: command-line, bash, command-history, shutdown

I am trying Ubuntu Server 10.10 in VirtualBox. I like that the commands I run is saved in a "history"-file that can be shown with the `history` command. But if I just turn off VirtualBox without the `shutdown` command, then next time when I boot, the commands from the last session is not saved in the history file.

The commands are only saved if I shutdown the machine with the `shutdown` command. E.g. `shutdown -P 0`.

Is there any way I can save the history file after every command so they are persistent even after a "non-clean" shutdown?

Comment: Also see [better-bash-history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/better-bash-history)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should always use `shutdown`.

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

This will append the in-memory history to your history file after each command is completed.

Comment: Don't you need `history -n` also?  That way anything appended to the history file by *this* terminal is read in by the *other* terminal?

Comment: It's even more complicated than that.  This appears to be the correct answer: https://superuser.com/a/734410

Comment: @Diagon: That looks like it results in a better quality history file, but it could add significant overhead since it reads the history file for every prompt if you keep a large one as I do.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I also keep a large one. The issues involved do not appear simple. For you or anyone else who might be interested, there has been extensive discussion on these issues, both [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18443) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338285/prevent-duplicates-from-being-saved-in-bash-history#). Since I would not only like a combined history, but also have some record of what I did, particularly in case I screw up, I'm considering [this](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2012/03/07-all-bash-history-revisited-load-time-solved-plus-directory-history).

Comment: @Diagon: I use a form of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960684/26428) and save the entries in a file separate from `.bash_history`. I have it record the directory that I'm in when I execute the command along with other information in addition to the command line.

Comment: That looks *fantastic*.  You've even got a switch for the tty!  I'll probably have a question or two, but I'll ask over there.  Maybe you want to consider putting it on github (or some non-MS version thereof)?