# Why would anyone not set 'histappend' in bash?

Tags: bash, command-history

After finding out what this `shopt -s histappend` [means](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/better-bash-history/1292#1292), it seems a very sane setting, and I'm surprised that it isn't default. Why would anyone want to wipe their history on each shell exit?

Comment: aside from the misunderstanding of what this option does - corrected by @maxscchlepzig - "default" has at least two sources: `bash` 'pure' or a distro-supplied `.bashrc`. for the former, @Gilles is probably correct. in the latter sense, `-s histappend` _is_ default on, e.g., Debian, since 2008: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=452459

Comment: Well, unix isn't exactly famous for sane defaults? I've come to expect the most unfriendly defaults by default :P (minor exaggerated)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Well, when `histappend` is not set, this does not mean that the history is wiped on each shell exit. Without `histappend` bash reads the histfile on startup into memory - during operation new entries are added - and on shell exit the last HISTSIZE lines are written to the history file without appending, i.e. replacing the previous content.

For example, if the histfile contains 400 entries, during bash runtime 10 new entries are added - histsize is set to 500, then the new histfile contains 410 entries.

This behavior is only problematic if you use more bash instances in parallel. In that case, the history file only contains the contents of the last exiting shell.

Independent of this: There are some people who want to wipe their history on shell exit because of privacy reasons.

Comment: Also, for security reasons, it can be a good idea to not save history for the root user. This feature allows root to have a shell history without it ever being saved to disk.

Comment: +1 for "does not mean that the history is wiped on each shell exit". This is explained perfectly well elsewhere - but perhaps not succinctly enough to reach some readers, especially in the context of the option's name (OK, I might have been one of those readers for awhile). @Mei, how does either permutation of `histappend` have any relevance to whether `root`'s history reaches a disk? Again, it only affects **what** is written, not _if_.

Comment: does anyone run less than 2 bash instances? `histappend` as well as `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups:ignorespace` seems like a good default for most people.

Comment: Is `histappend` effective meaningless if I have `HISTFILESIZE=` and `HISTSIZE=` for infinite history?

Comment: @Marc.2377 No, without `histappend` new history from concurrently running shells would then be lost and only the entries of the last exiting shell would be saved. Btw, I don't know if `HISTSIZE=` has the same effect as a negative `HISTSIZE`.

Comment: @dashesy I personally don't like to ignore/erase duplicate entries. I have HISTTIMEFORMAT enabled, and I like to be able to go back and see _when_ I issued a command... and if I issued it multiple times, I like to know when each one was issued. It's a personal preference, to which their own. ;)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226214/why-does-history-not-overwrite-but-append-when-histappend-is-set-to-off-in-bash/428208#428208

Answer (score 12):

For historical compatibility, I guess. The `histappend` option didn't exist until bash 2.0.

Comment: Was history overwritten each time?

Comment: @Tshepang: Yes, same as now if you don't use `histappend`.

Comment: it should be the default now but it is not