# Why does history not overwrite but append when histappend is set to off in Bash?

Tags: bash, command-history, shopt

Several days ago, I had one Terminal tab doing `ssh`, and the other doing a lot of work locally.  And then I restarted the machine (on a Mac with Mavericks).

When I ran Terminal again, I found that all the command history of the 2nd tab was not there.  There was only the `ssh` command.

So then I searched for how to "merge" the history somehow, and found that we need to do a `shopt -s histappend` in our `~/.bashrc` file so that history will append, instead of "overwrite" -- we don't want one set of history overwriting the other set; we want to append.

However, when I go to the OS X Yosemite box, and used `shopt`, I saw that `histappend` is off, but when I opened up two tabs, one doing `echo abc`, and the other doing `echo def`, and exited them, I re-opened Terminal again and issued a `history` command, and saw both the `echo abc` and `echo def` commands.

And then I ran Ubuntu 2014-10 on VirtualBox and did similar things, and still saw both history recorded (I first ran `shopt -u histappend` in both Bash to set the option to off first).

So what mechanism is doing that really?  Then `histappend` has no significance, if setting it to on or off doesn't matter?

I also commented out the `shopt -s histappend` in my `.bashrc` and restarted Terminal and tried again, and saw the history of both tabs able to combine... so this is really strange behavior and what can be causing it?

Comment: What is your `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: when I do `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`, it shows `update_terminal_cwd;` on Mavericks

Comment: And what's `trap -p` return?

Comment: I can't find the man page for `trap`... so I don't feel ok to run it... can you reproduce the issue by doing some changes to `trap`'s value instead of asking me to do this and do that?

Comment: Please read man bash, search for builtin for details about `trap`. I can't help if you don't give the information.

Comment: on the Mac it wasn't giving much info at all, and on Ubuntu it is no man page for `trap` and I suspect man page for bash won't give much info at all like the Mac.  Any way, `trap -p` gave nothing back on the Mac.  Hopefully next time you won't ask me what `\rm -rf ~` returns (which erases all your files)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I had the exact same doubt today. I suggest you check out this https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2016-05/msg00022.html     so as long as number of new entries this session is less than or equal to the  length of the history list, force append will happen, the `histappend' option doesn't have an effect.

Answer (score 3):

[@David Dai](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226214/why-does-history-not-overwrite-but-append-when-histappend-is-set-to-off-in-bash#comment747574_226214) is correct about this bash-help thread.

[Here](https://github.com/tpruzina/bash/blob/master/bashhist.c#L428-L437) is the relevant `bash` code in C.

```
if (history_lines_this_session <= where_history () || force_append_history)
  {
    result = append_history (history_lines_this_session, hf);
    history_lines_in_file += history_lines_this_session;
  }
else
  {
    result = write_history (hf);
    history_lines_in_file = history_lines_this_session;
  }
```

`shopt -s histappend` sets `force_append_history` to non-zero (`true`).

`history_lines_this_session` is the number of commands you typed this interactive `bash` session. When you first start bash, it is 0. It increases by 1 each time you <kbd>Enter</kbd> a command that is saved to history.

`where_history()` is an index into the in-memory history list, starting at index 0. It points to the next index to write history to. For example, when you have 0 history, it will be index 0. When you have 6 lines of history, it will be index 6.

When you first start `bash` and you have history in your `HISTFILE`, `where_history()` increase but will be limited to `<= HISTSIZE`. So `where_history()` has a maximum value of `HISTSIZE`.

After reading the `HISTFILE`, `where_history()` will increase but `history_lines_this_session` will still be 0. When you <kbd>Enter</kbd> `HISTSIZE + 1` number of commands, `history_lines_this_session == HISTSIZE + 1` and `where_history() == HISTSIZE` (because it is capped at the maximum). At this point, `(history_lines_this_session <= where_history()) == false` so history will be overwritten if `histappend` is off.

You can test this out in your `bash` yourself. If `histappend` is off, once you run `HISTSIZE + 1` number of commands, `history_lines_this_session` will exceed `where_history()` by 1 and `HISTFILE` will be overwritten. You have to make sure other commands aren't messing with your history for the test to work though (happens on macOS). Use the following commands to turn off commands that may mess with history:

```
trap - EXIT
PROMPT_COMMAND=
SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0 # for macOS only
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `histappend` is the behaviour set for **one** terminal.

Try the following in a new terminal:

```
shopt -s histappend
export HISTSIZE=1
export HISTFILESIZE=500
```

Then close the terminal. You will then see how your history file has the last 499 last commands it already had plus "`export HISTFILESIZE=50`", which you just typed. Your history was appended and then truncated to 500.

Now try this in another new terminal:

```
shopt -u histappend
export HISTIZE=1
export HISTFILESIZE=500
```

And again, close the terminal. You will see how now your terminal has just one command "`export HISTFILESIZE=500`".

The trick is that without `histappend`, the history file is overwritten with what there currently is in the terminal history (one command).

You won't notice it's behaviour if `HISTFILE` = `HISTFILESIZE` but I believe it has nothing to do with working on multiple terminals, this must be managed by something else...