# How can I make bash not repeatedly cut its history file

Tags: bash, environment-variables, command-history

I just want the .bash_history file to store a lot of history, like `$HISTSIZE=10000000, $HISTFILESIZE=10000000` which I have set months ago.

It does not work. I just tried ^R <some old command>, no way: my history file is now at 100324 bytes.

I have a single history for all sessions. I guess it is related to the problem: some race conditions, whatever. So I tried multiple recipes for a common bash history. Now I have this one:

```
HISTSIZE=10000000
HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoredups

history() {
  _bash_history_sync
  builtin history "$@"
}

_bash_history_sync() {
  builtin history -a         #1
  HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE     #2
  builtin history -c         #3
  builtin history -r         #4
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_bash_history_sync
```

Do not ask me what it means. It is just another copy&paste in a hope that the history file won't repeatedly lose contents despite the large limits.

Question: how to have both common history across sessions and `$HISTSIZE, $HISTOFILESIZE` be the only ultimate limits of history size, nothing else trying to help them?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll always find it contains the history of the last session closed, being overwritten when the next one closes.  I may be mistaken.

Comment: I can see stuff in my bash history that I did 16 days back, and I power down every night and cold-boot every morning. Maybe try a cron or shutdown job that rolls off the history to dated files that you can search.

Comment: @Gerard what is then the use of `shopt -s histappend` and `builtin history -a`?

Comment: Sorry, I only use ksh.

Comment: see this answer to another question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428208/4721

Comment: @Tim I see some reverse engineering there and hypotheses that history append works only for a single session. Did I get it right? Does it mean that Bash version of sharing history is not totally compatible with... sharing history?

Comment: My experience is that if you have two shells open, each loads the history file at the time they're started into HISTORY.  When they end, they write it back out.  So, shell1 writes it's history to .bash_history, then you close 2, and it write *its* history to .bash_history, thereby overwriting the history that was saved from shell1.