# How to preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows

Tags: bash, command-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)

While working, usually I have multiple terminal windows open (or tabs). I use konsole, but it could be few ssh sesions to one and the same machine, or using screen.

In any case, I'm looking for a way to preserve the history from each one of them on closing (or even better - while still open) and merged, so it can be reused later from any new session (or even the current opened ones). Any idea how to accomplish this?