# Update bash history on other terminals when exiting one terminal

Tags: bash, shell, command-history, signals

I know this question is not obscure, as it is asked here [keep updating](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) (and [duplicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25334/how-to-preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) here).

What I'm trying to achieve is a bit different. I don't like the idea of my prompt rewriting a file every `ls` I type (`history -a; history -c; history -r`).

I would like to update the file on exit. That's easy (actually, default), but you need to append instead of rewriting:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

Now, when a terminal is closed, I would like to make all others that remain open to be aware of the update.

I prefer to do this without checking via `$PS1` on every `command` that I type. I think it would be better to capture some sort of signal. How would you do that? If not possible, maybe a simple `cronjob`?

How can we solve this puzzle?

Comment: Note that zsh does this out of the box (and has many options to fine-tune history sharing).

Comment: Thanks @Gilles ; Funny, years using Linux and I never tried anything but `bash`. Maybe its time to check something new, just for fun.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Creative and involving signals, you say? OK:

```
trap on_exit EXIT
trap on_usr1 USR1

on_exit() {
    history -a
    trap '' USR1
    killall -u "$USER" -USR1 bash
}

on_usr1() {
    history -n
}
```

Chuck that in `.bashrc` and go. This uses signals to tell every `bash` process to check for new history entries when another one exits. This is pretty awful, but it really works.

---

**How does it work?**

[`trap` sets a signal handler](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap) for either a system signal or one of Bash's internal events. The `EXIT` event is any controlled termination of the shell, while `USR1` is `SIGUSR1`, a meaningless signal we're appropriating.

Whenever the shell exits, we:

- Append all history to the file explicitly.
- Disable the `SIGUSR1` handler and make this shell [ignore](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap) the signal.
- Send the signal to all running `bash` processes from the same user.

When a `SIGUSR1` arrives, we:

- Load all new entries from the history file into the shell's in-memory history list.

Because of the way Bash handles signals, you won't actually get the new history data until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the next time, so this doesn't do any better on that front than putting [`history -n`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-history) into `PROMPT_COMMAND`. It does save reading the file constantly when nothing has happened, though, and there's no writing at all until the shell exits.

---

There are still a couple of issues here, however. The first is that [the default response to `SIGUSR1` is to terminate](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) the shell. Any other `bash` processes (running shell scripts, for example) will be killed. `.bashrc` is not loaded by non-interactive shells. Instead, [a file named by `BASH_ENV` is loaded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files): you can set that variable in your environment globally to point to a file with:

```
trap '' USR1
```

in it to ignore the signal in them (which resolves the problem).

Finally, although this does what you asked for, the ordering you get will be a bit unusual. In particular, bits of history will be repeated in different orders as they're loaded up and saved separately. That's essentially inherent in what you're asking for, but do be aware that up-arrow history becomes a lot less useful at this point. [History substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) and the like will be shared and work well, though.

Comment: I wonder if you enabled time stamping within the `.bashrc` file, and then had something like a cronjob come along and resort the file periodically, sending a `SIGUSR1` as per you snippet, whether you could regain chronological up-arrow history?

Comment: It's a neat solution, but for the fact other processes terminate upon USR1. Does this behavior also happens with USR2?

Comment: I'll add a second comment, because I'm astonished. How come process associate TERM with USR1? Isn't USR1 something to be used only by the user?? Is this some `linux bug`?? Why other process are catching USR1? (I know its not meant to be discussed here, but maybe I'll bring this to light in the correct place)

Comment: The default behaviour of almost all signals is to terminate; [it's specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html). It's not a bug. Bash will let you specify that the signal will be ignored for all its processes, though, so that's fine for our purposes.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHomer . Is this specification you meant done by `BASH_ENV` as stated in this answer? Or do you know a more standard way to turn off this evil?

Comment: Yes, I described how to disable it in the answer.

Comment: Instead of `on_exit()` function, can I just include the code into `.bash_logout`? Its a trap less to handle.

Comment: To answer my own comment, because `.bash_logout` wont run in a terminal. Only in login shells. [here](http://superuser.com/questions/410525/explain-why-bash-logout-wont-run-commands)

Comment: Now, I tested this script! `Awsome!` I just made 2 small changes: use `USR2`, because you never know when you are going to need to trap `USR1`. And an echo message right in the begin of function `on_usr2()` stating: `echo 'I sense a disturbance in the force...'`. Star wars rocks. And it will remind you that the history has changed, to be more carefull with a fast "up+enter"