# Why does default bash seem to not have some of the commands I've used in history but does have others?

Tags: bash, command-history

On a Mac, Sierra.

I have no `HIST` related settings that I can see:

```
~ @ Magni (jcollum) 
$ env|grep HIST

~ @ Magni (jcollum) 
$ cat ~/.bash_profile | grep HIST

~ @ Magni (jcollum)
```

But I have things in my history that I did yesterday that are not there after a restart. Really really doubt I put spaces before the command every time I did it.

I know there are posts on here that tell me how to fix it but I would like to know **why** it happens this way.

For instance when I grep for a `curl` that I ran yesterday, nothing:

```
~ @ Magni (jcollum) 
$ history | grep curl 
166  curl -X POST -d email=jollum@gmail.com -d password=********** http://localhost:3000/login
503  hg curl 
519  history | grep curl
```

400 commands ago? I know I've used `curl` a dozen times in the past week but (and I don't use bash enough to have run hundreds of commands this week).

Basically I'm just perplexed and don't know why it's missing so much of what I did. Is it possible that history is only being recorded from one bash instance?

Comment: "history is only being recorded from one bash instance?" - yes.

Comment: [Related 1: Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/73093), [Related 2: Update bash history on other terminals when exiting one terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212646/73093),

Comment: You would likely need `set` rather than `env` in your first command, also, though I doubt it makes a difference.

Comment: Bash saves the history to a file, when it exits.  If it gets killed, it doesn't save the history.  If you recently restarted, maybe things didn't exit properly.

Comment: `set` might be more suitable since the `HIST*` variables could be set in `bashrc` and not exported, so `env` wouldn't see them. But that doesn't seem to be the (only) issue here.

Comment: What bash also does is that it doesn't save commands that have space as leading character.

Comment: "Really really doubt I put spaces before the command every time I did it." -- in OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that history is only being recorded from one bash instance?

That's kind of what's happening. The way history works in bash, unless you've gone to some lengths to change it, is:

- When bash starts, it loads saved history from the history file.
- Each time a command is executed, it's added to the history in bash's memory.
- When bash exits, it saves the accumulated history to the history file.

Now suppose you start two instances of bash. Both load the history file when they start. Both add the commands they run to their own history. When one instance exits, it saves the old history plus its own commands to the history file. When the second instance exits, it saved the old history plus *its* own command to the history file — and in doing this, it wipes the history from the first instance that exited.

Bash's history saving mechanism is overly simplistic. Your history lines are at the mercy of every other running instance — whichever exits last wipes the others' history. Solutions include appending the new history to the history file instead of overwriting the history file with the whole in-memory history, or appending lines to the history file as soon as they are executed. See [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) and [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) for some ways of implementing this and other variants.

The simplest solution is to run zsh, which saves history in a sane way by default. I recommend this, especially since you're running macOS which is stuck at an ancient version of bash because Apple doesn't like the license of versions released since 2009.

Comment: Excellent explanation and advice. I looked around after posting this and came to the same conclusion about `zsh`.