# Excluding some of the commands from being getting stored in bash history

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there any way to exclude commands like `rm -rf`, `svn revert` from being getting stored in bash history? Actually I, by mistake, have issued them a number of times even though I have no intent to do, just because I am doing things quickly and it happened. Hence results in lost of lots of work I have did so far.

Comment: You might be interested in http://serverfault.com/questions/48769/avoid-to-keep-command-in-history

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You might want `$HISTIGNORE`: "A colon-separated list of patterns used to decide which command lines should be saved on the history list." This line in your ~/.bashrc should do the job:

```
HISTIGNORE='rm *:svn revert*'
```

Also, you can add a space at the beginning of a command to exclude it from history. This works as long as `$HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`, which is default on any distro I've used.

Comment: space is how I've always done it.

Comment: I used to accidentally enter additional `y`, after all `cp` (aliased to `cp -i`) get over. So I aliased `y` as
`alias y='$(history | awk '"'"'END{if(NF==2 && $2=="y"){print "history -d " $1}}'"'"')'` ... But `HISTIGNORE` is better method as it looks. :) Thanks.

Comment: Just to be more explicit: you can add `export HISTCONTROL="ignorespace"` to your `~/.bashrc` to ignore commands that start with spaces.

Comment: @AidanFeldman not default on macOS

Comment: NOTE: space should be included when we type in the commandline and not in HISTIGNORE.

Comment: On Fedora 39 `echo $HISTCONTROL` prints only `ignoredups` (ignore duplicate entries).

Answer (score 8):

Though going slightly different from OP's question, when I intentionally don't want a command to get stored in bash history, I prefix them with a space. Works in Ubuntu and its variants, not sure if it works on all systems.

Comment: Depends on `$HISTCONTROL` (see my answer).

Comment: @l0b0 right, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

I usually kill my bash-instance when I have done things that I don't want in  the history.

```
kill -9 $$
```

$$ represents the current process - bash when you run it from the shell. You can use $BASHPID, but that's more typing :-)

Comment: Some Bash settings (like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows/1292#1292)) will save the history after each command, and in that case this won't work.

Comment: I used to do this. but setting `HISTFILE=/dev/null` is a better option.

Comment: simply `HISTFILE=` works in both bash and ksh.

Comment: or `unset HISTFILE`