# Prevent dangerous commands from going into bash history

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

What's the easiest way to prevent dangerous commands matching a pattern (like `rm`) from going into the Bash command history? I'd like to keep them away from the history of the current session, not just from the `.bash_history` file.

Comment: Like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32460/117549 ?

Comment: Thank you. I followed some links from that page and cobbled together an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

OK, seems there have been a few somewhat similar questions. The answer is to use:

```
export HISTIGNORE="rm*"
```

(It seems to be using glob syntax, and multiple patterns can be given by separating with colons `:`)

Another way is to set:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

which will cause Bash to keep all commands starting with a space out of the history. So if you can get into the habit of typing *space*-`rm`-*whatever* this will work fine.

To keep both *space*-commands and duplicate commands out of the history, you can do:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

It's also possible to use both `HISTIGNORE` and `HISTCONTROL`.