# Is there a way to make the history when pressing up in bash shared between shells?

Tags: bash, command-history

I've seen this answer:

[Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)

This works for history, but I'm wondering if there is way to extend this so pressing "up" is shared as well?

Comment: How does this differ from the second point in the post you linked?

Comment: it's not, but none of the solutions I saw seemed to accomplish that point

Comment: You need to get a new prompt by pressing enter in the second terminal after running the command in the first.

Answer (score 1):

While `bash` doesn't have this exact behavior, `zsh` can do this with

```
setopt inc_append_history share_history
```

See [How do you share history between terminals in zsh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23630/how-do-you-share-history-between-terminals-in-zsh)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by telling bash to write out and re-read the history after each command. Untested:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND"$'\nhistory -a; history -n'
```

Sharing the history is the default behavior of ksh. In zsh, you get this behavior by turning on the [`share_history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-SHARE_005fHISTORY) option, and you can get much finer control over how the history is saved and merged by tweaking other [history options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History).