# How to save command line history without logout?

Tags: bash, command-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make the history when pressing up in bash shared between shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-history-when-pressing-up-in-bash-shared-between-shell)

I am opening more than one console tab and I want to use commands that executed from first console tab from new opened console tab.

Is this possible to use commands that executed from first tab from second tab that not opened currently?

How can I use console history synchronously between consoles?

Comment: Shared history seems to be possible with some effort, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103944/real-time-history-export-amongst-bash-terminal-windows). I haven't tried it myself,  so I don't know how reliable it is. `zsh`, on the other hand, has it built in.

Comment: The part you added to your question is a duplicate of an existing question: [Is there a way to make the history when pressing up in bash shared between shells?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36886)

Comment: I think the whole thing is a duplicate; I'm going to close it

Comment: I am using zsh & oh-my-zsh now. This feature coming by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, `history -a` should append the ``new'' history lines (history lines entered since the  beginning of the current bash session) to the history file.

Comment: Thanks @choroba.This is good and solve first question. I added a new question to post.How can I use history synchronously?.This is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do it with a series of settings, such as (and I haven't fully tested this)...

`export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -c; history -r'`

That will cause the most recent command to be appended to your `.bash_history` file, then clear your shell history, then re-read the `.bash_history` file, each time the shell prompt is printed... so each time you run a command.

So, commands from one terminal will be appended to `.bash_history` every time they're run, then the second terminal will pick them up when it re-reads the history file.

Now, keep in mind that this is not realtime, as your second shell will not re-read the history file that was just written by the first shell until a command is run, but it's probably as close as you'll get with bash.

You may find value in setting your `HISTCONTROL` envvar to `ignoredups` or `erasedups`, or this option may not work so well for you.

`export HISTCONTROL='erasedups'`

Comment: [The last time we had this question,](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-history-when-pressing-up-in-bash-shared-between-shell), I suggested `history -a; history -n`. I didn't test it either.

Comment: actually, i went ahead and did this on my dev system, and it's working pretty well.  rotating shells are always 1 command behind, but a simple `test` or `echo foo` triggers history to update, and then you have access to the same command history from multiple shells.  Thanks, for the hint on `-n`, i'm going to play with that tomorrow. :)

Comment: For some reason, this creates a lot of duplicates in my .bash_history file. Since I'm saving the time stamp for each command (by using `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "`), I can see that the all have the same timestamp. They don't show up as duplicates when I run `history`, though.

Comment: That may have been a result of me not using the exact line you suggested, but `export PROMPT_COMMAND='time (history -a; history -c; history -r)'`, in order to see how much this slowed my system down :-) (this never detected anything longer than 0.07 seconds in real time, btw, so not an especially large delay)

Answer (score 0):

Part 2: According to the documentation `history -r` should read the history file in and replace the current history record.

Not sure what you mean by 'synchronously' but if you mean the automated synchronization of the histories of 2 console windows/tabs then I think the answer is NO. You have to do it manually.