# Preserve tcsh history in multiple terminal windows

Tags: command-history, tcsh

How can we preserve or maintain the same history across multiple terminals?

The same question, but for bash shell , were discussed in the below link

[Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)

let me know the corresponding settings for tcsh shell ?

Comment: For more information on tcsh's `history`, see `man tcsh`.  Searching for `history -S` should jump you to the most relevant part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These variables set the history to merge itself instead of overwrite, and not save duplicates:

```
set history=1000
set histdup=erase
set savehist=(1000 merge)
```

the secret sauce is this line:

```
alias precmd 'history -S; history -M'
```

which will save and merge your history prior to printing the prompt - i.e. after each command you type.

all of the above should be added to your ***.tcshrc*** file.

Comment: When I added this `alias precmd 'history -S; history -M'` nothing occurred when I wrote any command. Is there something else that should be done?

Comment: @AymanSalah what occurs is not obvious - it's the `.history` file (or `histfile` shell variable value, if set) getting written to disk.  *Without* the `precmd` alias set, `ls -l .history` will show the `.history` file as a untouched.  *With* `precmd` set as above, `ls -l .history` will show the updated timestamp and size, as it gets written with each command.

Comment: @Randall Thank you for pointing that out. I had problems then with the shell session. What you're saying is 100% correct.

Comment: This answer made my command number jump in large increments (sometimes thousands).  The solution here worked for me: https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070715091413640

Comment: @PeterGluck I too have the problem of tcsh history numbering being messed up (I'm at >30,000) regardless of whether I use this method or the one you referenced. Here's an archived URL for the above: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20221001183120/http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070715091413640

Comment: There is a very thorough answer here that explains this and when to use precmd or postcmd: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148742/tcsh-save-command-in-a-history-only-if-the-command-was-successful

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Idan answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199293/358323), I want to add that `alias precmd 'history -S; history -M'` potentially can mess up the history file, since it also records SIGINT and EOF signal (Ctrl+C and Ctrl+D).

[image]

A better way would be save and merge current shell history after running a command.

You can achieve it by this setup below instead, since the tcsh doesn't recognize SIGINT or EOF as a valid command.

```
alias postcmd       "history -S; history -M"
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer, and should have been the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

A single global history file is generally not what is desired, as it garbles command sequences when working on several tabs simultaneously.

If you want to keep your history PER TAB, use this approach:

```
set histfile=~/.history_`tty|sed "s#^.*/##"`
set history=1000
set savehist=(${history} merge)
alias postcmd 'history -S'
```

This will create individual history files for each tab, depending on their tty ID.

Using xfce4-terminal, if you do not change the order of tabs, and don't close tabs except the rightmost ones, this will correctly restore each history to its associated tab (and therefore, path).
As re-ordering tabs takes the tty ID with them, but a xfwm4 session restore will re-create each tab from scratch (assigning new tty IDs starting from 0), it would restore the history files to the "wrong" tab (i.e., not the one with the directory path of their original tab). I haven't found a solution yet how to keep track of these changes.