# How to sync terminal session command history in bash?

Tags: bash, command-history, synchronization

I've
 tried to search in `~/.bash_history` for my recent commands while in a 
terminal session but they just weren't there. I guess this is because I 
have multiple terminal sessions open.

Is there a way that I can sync (ie. sync-push or sync-write-out) the 
current terminal session's command history into the bash_history file 
(without closing the session and losing that environment)?

(It would be remotely similar in idea to how the `sync` command stores 
the file-system modifications on some systems.)

I imagine I could set up bash to preserve multiple session history but 
the ability to push the current history buffer would still be useful in 
scenarios when you are working on a new machine and you accidentally 
forgot to set up bash the way you may would have wanted.

Comment: I've tried `history -a` [shell builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) but somehow I now get 'permission denied' on the `.bash_history` file, after that.

Comment: Duplicated question. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add this line to `.bashrc`:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n"
```

Open new terminal and check.

**Explanation**

- `history -a` appends new history lines to history file.
- `history -n` tells `bash` to read lines that is not read from history file to current history list of session.
- `PROMPT_COMMAND`: contents of this variable is run as regular command before `bash` show prompt. So every time after you execute a command, `history -a; history -n` is executed, and your `bash` history is synced.

Comment: thanks! I don't know why did I get permission denied before but with new terminals now this seems to work as expected! I guess I should normally be able to use `history -a` in a terminal with unmodified bashrc too.

Comment: when do one have to start to worry about the performance implications of this? (I'm thinking about low-end devices, not sure how big overhead this makes.)

Comment: Also you might already have a prompt command, in this case it is better to use `export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND};history -a; history -n"`

Comment: If `${PROMPT_COMMAND}` is empty this gives an error because of the leading `;`

Comment: @BorisDäppen is right, but this is easily remedied `export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND}${PROMPT_COMMAND:+;}history -a; history -n"`

Comment: I would advise against messing with history after every command. I'm not sure about you, but when I press Up, I expect to see the command that was executed in this particular shell. The same goes for `sudo !!`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613925/29867).

Answer (score 5):

While I like being able to share history between terminals, especially new terminals. I would not want to share each and every command as it happens, as one window is often doing a specific task, separate form other windows. I would have them merge on shell exit, or when I request.

For a long time I looked for a way to merge bash history (with timestamps), and nothing seemed acceptable to me...

Finally I just 'bit the bullet' and DIY'ed a script to merge, the on-disk ".bash_history" with the in-memory shell 'history'. Preserving timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Now when I source this (you could make it a alias or a function as you like), I use the alias 'hc'. My current shell session is merged between disk and memory, so history is updated from other previous merges, WHEN I WANT (or on logout from that shell via ".bash_logout").

Optionally you can remove unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's. Adjust to suit!

This is the result... https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

Enjoy.

Comment: +1 good point about not wanting to load history from other terminals constantly. I decided to go with `history -a` in the PROMPT_COMMAND, and run (an alias for) `history -n` when I do want to load history from other shells. Your scripts looks good but it's over-powered for my current needs.

Comment: My current problem is bash's multi-line handling.   On the startup history read, it does so BEFORE I set that I want multi-line history, so bash breaks all the multi-line commands to multiple single line commands!   ARggghhh...   Only does this on start up!  Not during normal save, merge or re-read.