# sometimes history commands are not stored in .bash_history

Tags: bash, command-history

I issued many commands yesterday in my CentOS 7. But when I wanted to retrieve these commands today, I found there was no any record. When I opened the file `.bash_history`, I still could not find the commands I issued yesterday but I found many old commands a few days ago. Why were the recent commands not stored? How can I increase the history capability?

Comment: Sometimes when the terminal is closed abnormally, history is not saved, it happened to me as well but I don't know the circumstances which are causing this behavior

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most likely cause for history items not to show up is not by setting `HISTFILE` to nothing or `HISTSIZE` to zero, it is by logging into the same machine twice and exiting with the second bash instance (in which you did little or nothing) after the one where you did a lot. 
By default Bash doesn't merge histories and the second Bash-exit overwrites the `.bash_history` that was so nicely update by the first Bash-exit.

To prevent this from happening you can append to the history file instead of overwriting, you can use the `histappend` shell option:

> If the histappend shell option  is  enabled
>          (see  the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below), the
>          lines are appended to the history file, otherwise the history  file  is
>          overwritten.

More details in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1292/33055) including how to use `HISTSIZE`, `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTCONTROL` to control size, duplicates etc.

Answer (score 4):

To modify history size use two BASH variables `HISTSIZE`, `HISTFILESIZE` (usually set in `.bashrc`).

Description from BASH man page:

> **HISTSIZE**
>                 The number of commands to remember in the command  history  (see
>                 HISTORY  below).   If  the value is 0, commands are not saved in
>                 the history list.  Numeric values less than zero result in every
>                 command  being  saved  on  the history list (there is no limit).
>                 The shell sets the  default  value  to  500  after  reading  any
>                 startup files.
>
> **HISTFILESIZE**
>                 The maximum number of lines contained in the history file.  When
>                 this  variable  is  assigned  a value, the history file is trun‐
>                 cated, if necessary, to contain no  more  than  that  number  of
>                 lines  by removing the oldest entries.  The history file is also
>                 truncated to this size after writing it when a shell exits.   If
>                 the  value  is  0,  the  history file is truncated to zero size.
>                 Non-numeric values and numeric values  less  than  zero  inhibit
>                 truncation.   The  shell  sets the default value to the value of
>                 HISTSIZE after reading any startup files.

As an example I have the following setup in my `.bashrc` file:

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Answer (score 4):

Verifiy that your `HISTCONTROL` shell variable is not set to `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`.

```
$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoredups  #this is ok
```

You can modify it by setting the value in your `~/.bash_profile` or your `~/.profile` file:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

From `bash` man page:

> HISTCONTROL
>
> A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.
>
> If the list of values includes `ignorespace`, lines which begin with a space character  are  not saved  in the history list.
>
> A value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved.
>
> A value of `ignoreboth` is shorthand for `ignorespace` and `ignoredups`.
>
> A value of `erasedups` causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved.
>
> Any value not in the above list is ignored.
>
> If `HISTCONTROL`  is  unset,  or does not include a valid value, all lines read by the shell parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value of `HISTIGNORE`.  The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of `HISTCONTROL`.

Comment: This answer is useful but not accurate. HISTCONTROL is not an environment variable, but a shell variable. On a typical system, "env | grep HISTCONTROL" will not report anything, use "declare -p | grep HISTCONTROL" instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen but the solution wasn't listed here.  The cause was just a simple copy+paste issue.  I was copying a command from another document and I had some extra white space on the clipboard.  For some reason this caused Ubuntu to not save the command to the history file.

[image]

The above image was the command I had in my clipboard form google docs.  This command ran but was omitted form my history.  I just went back and selected the command with no whitespace and then it appeared in the bash history.

Comment: One of the history options is to ignore (don't save) lines that start with a space. It's usually defaulted to on. This can be changed in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the OP, I found loosing history due to multiple terminals, and the 'random order' in which they may exit annoying.   I wanted to be able to transfer history from terminal to terminal, but I didn't want it done continuiously, only when needed, or to save it when a shell exits, merging it with other terminals.

This was the result...

Merge the on-disk ".bash_history" with the in-memory shell 'history'. Preserving timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Optionally removing unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's. Adjust to suit!

https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

I source the script using an alias 'hc', and from ".bash_logout", but only if I have not turned off history save (unset $HISTFILE, - a sort of 'private' shell session for some situations).

Enjoy.