# Bash reverse search across terminal tabs

Tags: bash, command-history

I found that my ~/.bash_history has record of all commands I typed in different terminal tabs. But when I do reverse-search (CTRL+r) it only shows commands from that particular tab from which I'm doing reverse search. How to enable reverse search so that it looks through all commands in ~/.bash_history rather than just current tab history?

Comment: If you don't mind switching shells, `ksh` will do this; in window1 I can type a command and it immediately shows up in the history on window2.   Sometimes you may need to press RETURN to make it resync properly.  Indeed, if you have an NFS mounted `$HOME` then this history update may appear across multiple servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is covered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows).

To answer your precise question- By default, the history file is read *once* at shell startup, and written *once* at shell exit. To fetch commands that appeared in the history file since the shell start, use the history update command `history -n`, or the combination `history -a ; history -c; history -r`. The difference between those is how the histories are merged.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to say I cannot do reverse -search in terminal tab A for the commands I typed in terminal tab B; unless I run `history -n` in terminal A?

Comment: The "once" rule applies to both. To get commands from A to file: have A either exit, or explicitly call `history -a`. To get them from file to B: have B either start after file is updated, or call `history -n` or `history -r` (the merging order differs between those). This is explained in the other answer.

Comment: I have accepted this answer but I wish there was an easier way to do this without manually running `history` commands when working across tabs.

Comment: Thank you, but there is- see the linked question. The solution involves using `PROMPT_COMMAND`.