# Is it possible to view another shell's history?

Tags: command-history

I am running something in a `bash` window that I don't want to interrupt or even suspend momentarily. Is it possible to view command history of that particular window's session? I have multiple windows open, so viewing `.bash_history` won't help much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `bash` doesn't support that. The history is kept in memory and not available for other processes until it is saved to `.bash_history` in the same session using `history -a` or `history -w`. But the moment it's written to the file system, the information from which session the command originated is lost.

The closest you can get is using some lines in `.bashrc` to let `bash` append every command directly after execution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1292/147970
Then you can see the commands from all shells in near real-time in `.bash_history`.

To access the history for a specific session you need to interrupt the foreground process in that session using e.g. `Ctrl+Z`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how with `gdb` (you'll need to run it with administrative permissions), via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272558/can-we-define-a-new-data-type-in-a-gdb-session :

preparation:

```
echo 'typedef void * histdata_t;
typedef struct _hist_entry {
  char *line;
  char *timestamp;
  histdata_t data;
} HIST_ENTRY;
typedef struct _hist_state {
  HIST_ENTRY **entries;
  int offset;
  int length;
  int size;
  int flags;
} HISTORY_STATE;
HIST_ENTRY _sampleentry;
HISTORY_STATE _samplestate;
' | tee sample.c
# get sample.o
gcc -g -c sample.c

# get bash pid, maybe via `pgrep bash`, or `pidof bash`, etc
# say in this example, it is 16573
```

Run test command:

```
$ sudo gdb -p 16573 -ex "set confirm off" -ex "add-symbol-file sample.o 0" -ex 'printf "ptype HIST_ENTRY\n"' -ex "ptype HIST_ENTRY" -ex 'printf "p *(HISTORY_STATE*)history_get_history_state()\n"' -ex 'p *(HISTORY_STATE*)history_get_history_state()' -ex 'set $myoffs = (*(HISTORY_STATE*)history_get_history_state())->offset' -ex 'printf "myoffs %d\n", $myoffs' -ex 'printf "p *(HIST_ENTRY *)history_get($myoffs)\n"' -ex 'p *(HIST_ENTRY *)history_get($myoffs)'
....
0x00007fb053abb0e9 in __pselect (nfds=1, readfds=0x7ffe81a009b0, writefds=0x0, exceptfds=0x0, 
    timeout=<optimized out>, sigmask=0x7ffe81a00930) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pselect.c:69
69  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pselect.c: No such file or directory.
add symbol table from file "sample.o" at
    .text_addr = 0x0
Reading symbols from sample.o...done.
ptype HIST_ENTRY
type = struct _hist_entry {
    char *line;
    char *timestamp;
    histdata_t data;
}
p *(HISTORY_STATE*)history_get_history_state()
$1 = {entries = 0x55ed117f4ab0, offset = 155, length = 155, size = 502, flags = 1}
myoffs 155
p *(HIST_ENTRY *)history_get($myoffs)
$2 = {line = 0x55ed119684d0 "kill -STOP $$", timestamp = 0x55ed119709a0 "#1545016332", data = 0x0}
```

prepare gdb "capture last history entry" command:

```
echo '
set verbose off
set complaints 0
set trace-commands off
add-symbol-file sample.o 0
set $myoffs = ((HISTORY_STATE*)history_get_history_state())->offset
set $line = ((HIST_ENTRY *)history_get($myoffs))->line
printf "%s\n", $line
' | tee gdbscript
```

run gdb "capture last history entry" command:

```
sudo gdb -p 16573 -batch -x gdbscript 2>/dev/null | tail -1
kill -STOP $$
```

Comment: I had to merge the last two lines of `gdbscript` down to `printf "%s\n", ((HIST_ENTRY *)history_get($myoffs))->line` and change `tail -1` to `tail -2 | head -1`

Comment: I'm not sure why but `history_get` is always returning `NULL` regardless of what argument is passed to it and I have to use `set $line = ((HISTORY_STATE*)history_get_history_state())->entries[$myoffs-1]->line` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can press Ctrl-Z to put task in background. After that you can work in your shell and see command history. To look tasks in background you can use `job` command. To back to your task run `fg` command.