# Possible to trigger history append (and save to file) in an already running bash process remotely?

Tags: bash, command-history

Let's say you have a `bash` terminal open, in which you have typed a lot of commands, many of which are probably not yet saved in `$HISTFILE`. Additionally, let's say that you have a long running command running in that terminal, so you can't really stop this command to issue `history -a` to append new entries to/flush to the `$HISTFILE`.

My question is: is it possible to trigger the equivalent of `history -a`, in a `bash` shell which has a process running inside it, remotely - that is, just by knowing this shell's PID? Maybe there's some sort of signal that can be issued to the running `bash` process - but could I issue that via bash or standard tools?

(I'm trying to develop a Python `psutil` script which will save settings of all my open `bash` terminals and their history files, and for this to make sense, I guess all these `bash` processes need to flush their unflushed lines to respective `$HISTFILE`s, before the script copies these files; and some of these shells may have long-running processes in them. So if this "remote history flush" is doable from another `bash` instance, then it will be doable via Python too...)

Comment: see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341534/is-it-possible-to-view-another-shells-history/489405#489405

Comment: Can't this long running command be even momentarily stopped for a Ctrl-Z and `bg`?