# bash terminal multi-tab history

Tags: bash, command-history

I want a *reliable* solution to hold *every* command in *every* terminal-tab in my **bash** **history**?

With *timestamps*, *ordered*, last commands last, and *unique*.

While open, each tab has its *own* list, so that I can use *history expansion* with **PS1**.

And new tabs take as the basis *all* the current and past commands.

Comment: There's a rather highly-voted question and answer on a similar subject in [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows). Perhaps you could see if it answers your question?

Answer (score 3):

I have all my stuff in a *single* file, **.bash_aliases**, which get sourced in *.bashrc*:

```
HISTMY="$HOME/.bash_history"    
touch $HISTMY

HISTSIZE=-1
HISTFILESIZE=-1
HISTCONTROL='ignoredups:ignorespace'
HISTTIMEFORMAT="|%d.%m._%a_%T|  "
HISTMYTERM=${HISTMY}_`tty|sed 's|^/dev/||;s|/|_|g'`

PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a $HISTMYTERM'

export MYHISTLOCK="/tmp/.my.hist.lock"
```

every tab has his file: *.bash_history_pts_{0..}*
plus the current *.bash_history* with old stuff

```
FBashHist ()
{
    local perl_history=$(cat <<'EOF'
########################################
#line 1526
use v5.10;

$file = $ARGV[0];
@ARGV = glob "$file*";

$time = "#" . (time - 1_000_000);

while (<>) {
    s/^\s*//;
    s/\s*$//;

    next if length() < 4;

    if (/^#\d{9,}$/) {
        $time = $_;
    }
    else {
        $cmd = $_;

        if (exists $hash{$cmd}) {
            next if $hash{$cmd} ge $time;
        }
        $hash{$cmd} = $time;
    }
}

@keys = sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash;

@keys = reverse @keys;
@keys = splice(@keys, 0, 8000);  # cmds to save
@keys = reverse @keys;

foreach $key ( @keys ) {
    push @hist, "$hash{$key}\n$key\n";
}

open BA, ">$file" or die "cant open '$file' for write: $!";
print BA @hist;
close BA;

EOF
)
###############################

perl -E "$perl_history" $HISTMY
}
```

A **perl** *hash* is per se *unique*, so I use it for *commands*. The values are the *timestamps*.

It must be ensured that this init runs on reboot for all tabs only *once*.

I use **flock** from *util-linux*. It creates an empty file, which locks the tabs. With append (>>), later runs don't reset it.

After 10 seconds, more than enough time to init, a rerun is possible.

```
### call with init lock
(
    flock -x 9

    if [ ! -s $MYHISTLOCK ]; then
        echo $$ >$MYHISTLOCK

        FBashHist
    else
        l=`stat -c %Y $MYHISTLOCK`

        (( $l )) && d=`date +%s` && ((d -= 10))

        if (( $l < $d )); then
            touch $MYHISTLOCK

            FBashHist
        fi
    fi
) 9>>$MYHISTLOCK
sleep 1
```