# Explanation of `history -c;` in the following well known snippet for preserving bash history

Tags: bash, tmux, command-history, macos

I am using the following code in my .bashrc file for keeping everything in history when I have multiple tmux panes open:

```
# Avoid duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

I have no problem with this on my linux machine. However on macOS, there is a little problem when using this with tmux specifically (meaning multiple opened asynchronous terminals without tmux work okay).

What then happens is that a new pane in tmux has completely empty history.

Here is a reference comment in question [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows), showing the same problem on macOS with similar program `screen`:

[image: comment reference]

I tried to remove the `history -c;` part of the command and now the history in new tmux pane is not empty. However, I am not sure whether it is a working solution and what caveats it might have. Therefore, my main question is what role does the `history -c` play and why is it needed.

Note: *If you are unable to reproduce the problem, point it out and I will provide os versions, program versions and logs.*

Answer (score 0):

The simple, short answer is that, if you do not do an `history -c` before a `history -r` you would read the history **twice**.

The last command (and its number) is given with `fc -l -1`:

```
$ fc -l -1

19131    clear
```

If you read the history **file** again, you will duplicate most of the history (in memory, not in the file):

```
$ history -r; fc -l -1

38319    fc -l -1
```

That is the reason to have and use `history -c`.

### empty history

> What then happens is that a new pane in tmux has completely empty history.
> The workaround for that must be very simple: just execute

```
history -r
```

And all the history in the history file will reappear in memory.