# .bashrc history command not working when new terminal window opened

Tags: bash, command-history

I added some simple `history` command in order to get some info every time
I am on a `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` Dell local machine with `bash 4.4.20(1)-release`, shell `/bin/bash`. If I open a new shell:

```bsh
history | tail
```

but I noticed that when I open a new terminal it does show me anything, while if I:

```bsh
source ~/.bashrc
```

it works well. I guess it has something to do with `history` characteristics and new terminals but even googling and looking here I can not figure out what!

Thanks in advance for any help!

--- EDITED ---

```bsh
grep HIST ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile
/home/enrico/.bashrc:HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
/home/enrico/.bashrc:# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
/home/enrico/.bashrc:HISTSIZE=1000
/home/enrico/.bashrc:HISTFILESIZE=2000
/home/enrico/.bashrc:export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %T "
grep: /home/enrico/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/237982)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. Also show us the output of `grep HIST ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile` and the output of `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Also clarify how you are logging in to the machine. Is this a local machine? A remote one you access via ssh? Something else? Are you using a GUI?

Comment: Is the command in your `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile.d` ?

Comment: @bxm is in `.bashrc`, also edited the question accordingly to previous comments