# Search through bash history shared by multiple terminal windows, but keep sessions separate

Tags: bash, command-history

I've read the solutions at [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)
 and I'm looking for the following compromise:

1. Commands from all concurrent `bash` sessions are appended after being executed to one shared file
2. <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd> in one session finds commands from other sessions
3. Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> in one session [only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows#comment67052_48116) cycles through the commands in that session.

Is this possible with `bash`? If not, with `zsh` maybe?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. I mean, at least in `bash`, you can share one history file, but each session manages it's own history in the memory. You can merge the history from the file to the session, but then it would also affect up/down keys. What I suggest is to replace ctrl+r with a different script/alias that would search through the file, maybe with grep. It wouldn't be the same, of course, but that's what I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled upon this question while trying to achieve something similar. I believe the following solves your problem:

1. Use a file to record all executed commands. Thanks to Eli Bendersky for his [post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/06/11/keeping-persistent-history-in-bash), I use his code as it is, the only change is setting the filename in `$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_FILE`.
2. Install [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) with key bindings (I'm unsure if installation via package manager sets key bindings, but via git and install script does).
3. Change `__fzf_history` function in `fzf/shell/key-bindings.bash` to:

```
__fzf_history__() {
  local output opts script
  opts="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} --bind=ctrl-z:ignore ${FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS-} -n2..,.. --scheme=history --bind=ctrl-r:toggle-sort ${FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS-} +m --read0"
  script='BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $HISTCOUNT = $ENV{last_hist} + 1 } s/^[ *]//; print $HISTCOUNT - $. . "\t$_" if !$seen{$_}++'
  output=$(
    tac $PERSISTENT_HISTORY_FILE |
        last_hist=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T  ' builtin history 1) perl -n -l0 -e "$script" |
      FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="$opts" $(__fzfcmd) --query "$READLINE_LINE"
    ) || return
  READLINE_LINE=${output#*| }
  if [[ -z "$READLINE_POINT" ]]; then
    echo "$READLINE_LINE"
  else
    READLINE_POINT=0x7fffffff
  fi
}
```

Obviously, you can make your own function stripping the code above from fzf specifics and binding it to ctrl+r.

Comment: I have a personal script, now I'm trying to figure out how to use this with that... I thought, maybe, adding your modified function to my script after sourcing key-bindings would do the trick, but when I tried it I got an error: `unknown option: --scheme=history`...

Comment: Maybe it's something with your fzf version (too old/too buggy)? I've found this: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2996

Comment: I never paid attention that `apt`'s version is so outdated! Switched to `brew`'s install. It's working now, thank you very much!