# Sync terminal history in c shell

Tags: command-history, csh

For work, I remote into a linux server that uses c shell rather than bash using Remote Desktop. While in session (lets call it session 1) I'll open up many tabs in a given terminal and type commands throughout all of them. I'll also sometimes open up additional sessions (lets call them session 2 and session 3) with many tabs in their respective terminals and type many commands throughout all of them.

I have noticed that the history  command when invoked in any tab of any terminal across any session does not include all of the commands I have used across all of the tabs and sessions. only part of the commands are saved.

I would like a history that:

- Remembers *all* commands typed, regardless of what tab, terminal or session I am in
- Instantly accessible from any of tabs/terminals/sessions

While there is a great [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows/1292#1292) from nearly 12 years ago that describes how to do exactly this, that is for a bash environment, not a c shell environment. As such, there is no `.bashrc` but rather a `.cshrc`. I'm looking for a solution that works in the c shell environment.

UPDATE:

I tried adding this to the top of the `.cshrc` file:

```
set history=10000
set savehist=(10000 merge)
alias precmd 'history -L, history -S'
```

Where set `history=10000` sets the size of the history list,

`set savehist=(10000 merge)` sets the number of lines in the history list to save to the `.history` upon exit of a session, and the merge merges the history of a session with the overall history upon exit,

`alias precmd 'history -L; history -S'` sets some commands to run before every command at the terminal is ran. The `-L` option appends a history file to the current history list. The `-S` option writes the history list to a file.

This didn't do what I wanted. Now every time I type history at the terminal, the size of the command history list jumps up in size *dramatically*. The command history list *isn't* updated across terminal tabs in a session.

I tried this too, with no improvement:

```
set history = 10000
set histdup = erase
set savehist = (${history} merge lock)

alias precmd 'history -S'
alias postcmd 'history -M'
```

I'm not entirely sure what all of the lines mean, but I know that `precmd` supposedly means before a command is ran, do this and `postcmd` supposedly means after a command is ran do this. The `-M` option merges the contents of the history file with the current history list and sorts the resulting list by the timestamp contained with each command.

I feel like I am close, like I'm missing some key line to add in the `.cshrc` file, or maybe I need to change the order around.

Comment: Couple suggestions: first, does the server have multiple shells installed? If it does, you can actually change the shell on a per-user basis without administrator privileges using `chsh` (if you didn't know that - sorry if you do). If that's not an option, there might be a way to do this using GNU `screen` which is a pretty powerful tool for terminal multiplexing etc in its own right.

Comment: From what I've been told, we're highly encouraged not to change from csh. Reasons why flew over my head. So if possible, I'd like to find a way in to make these changes while remaining in csh. Additionally, I'd like to achieve this by making changes to `.cshrc`.