# history of new shell is missing the last few commands?

Tags: terminal, command-history

I've noticed this pretty much ever since I started using Unix systems many years ago, and never bothered to figure out why, abut now I am.

When I use terminal, and I want to use `history` to see a history of commands I've executed, it generates a list, but when I open a new shell while on the existing tab, when I execute `history` in the new tab, it's missing the last X commands, where X varies.

I am wondering why this is, and if it's possible for the new tab to have the same history as the tab it was opened from?

Comment: You need to set the shell to save history as it goes. They are often configured to only save on exit. They also only load the history on start.

Comment: see also [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)