# I can't get bash history to update instantly in all terminals

Tags: bash, command-history

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.3, with gnome-terminal, and I haven't directly edited ~/.bashrc.  Various sources say adding the following to it achieves what I'm looking for:

```
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

I then `source ~/.bashrc`.

What I want is for the following to happen.  I open two terminal windows.  In the first, I execute `echo 1`.  In the second I execute `echo 2`.  In the first I press the up arrow, and I see `echo 2`.  Instead what I see is `echo 1`.  That's to say bash window history is kept separate from each other.  If I close the windows, and then reopen one, then the histories are merged, but I want history to update for all windows as commands are executed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Bash is really not the shell for this. But: if you change `PROMPT_COMMAND` to [use `history -a; history -c; history -r` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48113/70524), you'll find that history from other terminals is added after you press Enter and get a new prompt. But bash really doesn't do updating state in the background. You still need to get a new prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to correctly invoke the `history -a` command before each prompt by making it part of the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` string.  This will append the current in-memory history to the history file.

However, appending the history to the history file will not automatically *read* the updated history from the same file, so you will need to do that separately using `history -n`.   This command will "read all history lines not already read from the history file
and append them to the history list" (that's from `help history` in the shell).  The "history list" is the in-memory command line history.

That means:

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Or, if you want to clear the in-memory history before re-reading all of the history from the history file (you may want to use this if you find that the above gives you an unintuitive ordering of commands in the history):

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

---

Note that if you `source` the `.bashrc` file several times, you will add more and more to the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` string.  If you are in a habit of doing this, it would potentially be better to do it like this instead:

```bash
original_prompt_command=${original_prompt_command-$PROMPT_COMMAND}
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; $original_prompt_command"
```

This sets the value of the variable `original_prompt_command` to the value of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable, if `original_prompt_command` is unset.  This new variable is then used to update `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  The effect is that if the file is sourced more times, the *original* `$PROMPT_COMMAND` value will always be extended and you will not get a longer and longer string.